# Topological space that is not homeomorphic to the disjoint union of its connected components

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

As the title says, I'm looking for a counterexample to the statement that every topological space X is homeomorphic to the disjoint union of its connected components.

I know that this is in fact true if X is locally connected because this implies that the connected components are open, but unfortunately, I don't have a sufficient repertoire of examples of spaces that meet certain conditions (in this case, not being locally connected).

Thanks in advance
J.Dillinger

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Two standard examples of [totally disconnected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space) spaces (that are not discrete) are $\mathbb{Q}$ (with the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}$) and the product $\{ 0, 1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ of countably many copies of the two-point discrete space (homemorphic to both the Cantor set and, if I recall correctly, the $p$-adic integers).

Generalizing the second example, any [Stone space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras) is totally disconnected. These spaces are important as they arise as the spectra of Boolean rings.

If you want to expand your repertoire of examples of spaces, it's hard to do better than Steen and Seebach's [Counterexamples in Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology).

Comment: Thanks!! It's quite obvious for Q endowed with the subspace topology, it just didn't come to my mind. (I will accept the answer as soon as the 5 minute limit ends)

Comment: The product of countably many copies of the two-point space should just be equivalent up to notation to the real interval [0,1], since you could think of each number in that interval in binary form

Comment: @Martin: this is a reasonable guess but it is not true. There are issues with non-uniqueness of binary expansions, e.g. $1 = 0.111 \dots$, and also with the topologies. The Cantor set has a quite different topology from $[0, 1]$, e.g. it is totally disconnected while $[0, 1]$ is connected.

Comment: That’s fine, we need to quotient by the equivalence relation if having an infinite repeated sequence probably, it gets a bit hairy, so as sets that infinite product and the binaries are not the same. However the binaries and the cantor set are quite certainly the same object up to notation as sets, up to changing 1’s for 2’s. The issue with the topologies of the Cantor set C & the binaries being differ. only arises if you toplogise the Cantor set with the usual topology thinking of the Cantor set as a subset of [0,1]. You can pull back a topol. on C from [0,1] under the map I described